# php mail function content layout

Tags: php, html, database, forms, hidden

From a html form a text is stored in a database.
With the following code I tried to mail that text to a reciepant:

```
$recipient = $emailadres;
    $subject = 'xxxx';
    $header = 'From: xxxx <xxx@xxxxxxxxx.nl>';
    if ($aanhef == 'Dhr.') {
        $geslacht = 'heer';
    }
    elseif ($aanhef == 'Mevr.') {
        $geslacht = 'mevrouw';
    }
    else {
        $geslacht = 'heer/mevrouw';
    }
    $mail_body = $bevestiging;
    $mail_body = str_replace('#geslacht#', $geslacht, $mail_body);
    $mail_body = str_replace('#achternaam#', $achternaam, $mail_body);
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```

in the variable mail_body the content of the mail is stored, after that gender and last name in the content are replaced. This php code works. However, if we looked at the recieved mail  all the enters filled in in the HTML form become two enters, in other words the whole layout of the email has changed, when I look into the database the text is there in normal layout, no double enters ect. But if I put in the text manually in the database it works normal. Is it possible that in the database a hidden html layout is stored? Or is it something else

Comment: check the email_body value/output before str_replace and after it...

Comment: before str replace the layout is already wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your $header variable to this:

```
$header ="Content-type: text/html; FROM: xxxx <xxx@xxxxxxxxx.nl>";
```

and the sent email will be displayed as HTML.

Comment: It worked, the only problem now is that the email is appearing to be from the web host in my mailbox, so directly caught by the spam filter

Comment: Oh! I missed the "\r\n" after the content-type.

$header ="Content-type: text/html\r\nFROM: xxxx <xxx@xxxxxxxxx.nl>";

that should do the trick. :)

Comment: The content is good now and i can add html tags everywhere i like but my hotmail says it is sent by atlantis@webhost.nl not by xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.nl

Comment: Can you paste the lines where you set the $header variable here?

Comment: $header = 'Content-type: text/html\r\n From: xxxxxxx <xxxx@sxxxxxx.nl>';